# How to make a simple popup box in Visual C# 2015 web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web, visual-studio-2015

As I know I can make a popup window in vs 2010 using MessageBox.Show() method. But it is not available in VS2015, so I want to know if there is any simple alternative to it. 
I am creating a web application using visual studio C# and no class System.Windows.Forms is available as given in the link.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is available in all versions of .net(including latest .net 4.6), see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20stz12s(v=vs.110).aspx).

But it is for `Desktop application`(winform/WPF) only, not available in `web` or `Console application`.

Comment: It's pretty easy to add to a console application. You just need to add the reference `System.Windows.Forms` to your project.

Comment: Yes I know, but its not referenced by default. Thats what I meant.

Comment: Any idea for web forms?

Comment: There is no message box for webforms in any version of .net. You can use alert, but its not recommended.

Comment: I mean any kind of popup window which usually comes when login fails

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you already have an answer to this but here is how I solved a similar problem using VS2015.

```
    var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Smaller Text Message", "Large Text Message");

    messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Try again", new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.emailRetryPasswordRetrieval)));
    messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Cancel", new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.emailRetryPasswordRetrieval)));

    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
```

Then in the method emailRetryPasswordRetrieval

```
private void emailRetryPasswordRetrieval(IUICommand command)
    {

        if (command.Label.Equals("Try again"))
        {
            mymethod();
        }
        if (command.Label.Equals("Cancel"))
        {
            anothermethod();
        }
    }
```

and dont forget to add:

```
using Windows.UI.Popups;
```